# Unchecked call to submitList(List<T>) as a member of the raw type ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack

I have been copying off the [Sunflower](https://github.com/hatewx/android-sunflower-java) android architecture best practices app and so far slow but successful, whilst my code works, it is showing an unchecked message so I ran the command it asked and it is saying this:

> [unchecked] unchecked call to submitList(List) as a member of the
>   raw type ListAdapter where T is a type-variable: T extends Object
>   declared in class ListAdapter

It probably isn't important but it is annoying me, the one i am using as reference never had any <> around ListAdapter or anything and had no warning, so i'm not sure why mine is.

My Fragment:

```
public class NewsFeedFragment extends Fragment {

    private PinViewModel viewModel;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FragmentNewsFeedBinding binding = FragmentNewsFeedBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        PinViewModelFactory factory = InjectorUtils.providePinListViewModelFactory(getContext());
        ListAdapter adapter = new PinListAdapter();
        binding.pinList.setAdapter(adapter);
        this.viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(PinViewModel.class);
        subscribeUi(adapter);
        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    private void subscribeUi(ListAdapter adapter) {
        this.viewModel.pins.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), pins -> {
            if (pins != null) {
                adapter.submitList(pins);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class PinViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private PinRepository pinRepository;

    public LiveData<List<Pin>> pins;

    PinViewModel(@NonNull PinRepository pinRepository) {
        this.pinRepository = pinRepository;
        this.pins = this.pinRepository.getPins();
    }
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class PinListAdapter extends ListAdapter<Pin, PinListAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    public PinListAdapter() {
        super(new PinDiffCallback());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(ListItemPinBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Pin pin = getItem(position);
        holder.bind(pin);
        holder.itemView.setTag(pin);
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ListItemPinBinding binding;

        ViewHolder(@NonNull ListItemPinBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        void bind(Pin item) {
            binding.setPin(item);
            binding.executePendingBindings();
        }
    }

    static class PinDiffCallback extends DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Pin> {

        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull Pin oldItem, @NonNull Pin newItem) {
            return oldItem.getId() == (newItem.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull Pin oldItem, @NonNull Pin newItem) {
            return oldItem == newItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using

```
ListAdapter adapter = new PinListAdapter();
```

That's throwing away the type information `PinListAdapter`. Specifically, the `ListAdapter<Pin, PinListAdapter.ViewHolder>` generic type information. Therefore your `subscribeUi` doesn't know that your `ListAdapter` takes a list of `Pin` objects and you get the error you are experiencing.

You can change your adapter to be a `PinListAdapter` and you'll get the type information you need.

Answer (score 0):

That example is written in Kotlin and not in Java ...

It is unclear what `List<T> pins` is; that probably should be `List<Pin> pins`:

```
if (pins != null && pins instanceof List<Pin>) {
    adapter.submitList(pins);
}
```

Comment: Someone added that link to the kotlin one (now changed), i am using the java one, which does not need that. I am happy to take that as a solution but i would be interested to know why his doesn't need it and mine does

Comment: Actually I've realised it shows "illegal generic type for instanceof"